# Visual Studio Git commands - Path, file name length error

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Whenever I try to pull or sync from git in visual studio, I get the error

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

[image: Visual Studio Git commands - Path, file name length error]

The local path where my repository is located : `C:\Users\user3008\Documents\Projects\clientconsultancyservice\ClientConsultancyInterface`

Both the `.vs` and `.gitignore` files are saved in the above directory. I never faced this issue in VS 2015 and have recently upgraded to VS2019.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Updating Visual Studio
2. Updating GitHub Extension

**Relevant Details:**

Visual Studio 2019 Professional v16.4.5

GitHub Extension for Visual Studio v2.10.8.8132

Comment: Try moving the local repository folder to `C:\GitSource` directly instead of `C:\Users\user3008\Documents\Projects\clientconsultancyservice\ClientConsultancyInterface`. The error is due to limitation of filname in dos, it has nothing to do with VS or GIt.

Comment: @stud3nt This doesn't make sense. For large projects in enterprises, the longest path may exceed 260 characters without even adding to the base directory

Comment: Try using this if it helps. `git config --system core.longpaths true`

Comment: @stud3nt No, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> The local path where my repository is located:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\user3008\Documents\Projects\clientconsultancyservice\ClientConsultancyInterface
> ```

And then add the longest path & file name in to repo to the starting point: if any go over 260 characters you;ll get that error., Blame MS-DOS 2.0 for the 260 character limitation.

Options: either use WSL, or (easier) put you repo somewhere more sensible on you machine where the location of the repo is a rather shorter name.

(I use `C:\Projects` and have changed VS's default project location to match.)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. For large projects in enterprises, the longest path may exceed 260 characters without even adding to the base directory.

Comment: @MM not if being developed on Windows they don't.

Comment: (Also you'll hit issues if there is a dependency on file/folder names differing only in case... and this applies to git refs as well.)